# clientWidth always returns zero on angular 9+

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Hello I want to get width and height from image but clientWidth always returns zero, here is my directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[image-fit]'
})
export class ImageFitDirective {

  constructor(
    private _elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this._fit();

  }

  private _fit(): void {
    let width: any = this._elementRef.nativeElement.clientWidth;
    let height: any = this._elementRef.nativeElement.clientHeight;

    // console.log(this._elementRef);
    console.log(width, height);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using like this?

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[image-fit]',  
  host: {
    '(click)':"_fit()"
  }
})
export class ImageFitDirective {

  constructor(
    private _elementRef: ElementRef
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this._fit()
  }

  _fit(): void {
    const width = this._elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    const height = this._elementRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    console.log('width', width)
    console.log('height', height) 
  }

}
```

Comment: Okay, but still won't work when you fire a click on the parent component?

Answer (score 0):

From [docs in developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)

> The Element.clientWidth property is zero for inline elements and
> elements with no CSS; otherwise, it's the inner width of an element in
> pixels. It includes padding but excludes borders, margins, and
> vertical scrollbars (if present).

You can use getBoundingClientRect()

```
private _fit(): void {
    const  rect=this._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
    let width: any = rect.width;
    let height: any = rect.height;

    console.log(width, height);

  }
```

BTW, if you want applied to an img, you should use the event **load** else gives the values 0 unless the image is "cached" by the browser

```
<img [src]="'https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1'" 
     (load)="onLoad($event.target)" >

onLoad(img:any)
{
   console.log(img.clientWidth,img.getBoundingClientRect())
}
```

**Updated** as always, if we has some under a div with a *ngIf like, e.g.

```
<div *ngIf="condicion">
  ..what ever...
</div>
```

We can not do

```
//this NOT WORK
condition=true;
myImageFitDirective._fit()
```

Because Angular has no "repaint" when we call to the function `_fit()`. We need enclosed by setTimeout

```
//now is OK
condition=true;
setTimeout(()=>{
   myImageFitDirective._fit()
})
```

Comment: _fit() still returns zeroes :( after loging

Comment: Really I don't know what happens -well you forget write `implements AfterViewInit` in the directive -but I don't know if is a typo error when you wrote the question-. BTW I added to my answer an update to take account the "problem with *ngIf" (I don't know if it is your case)